# What distribution is suited to modelling the difference between bus schedule and arrival times?

Tags: modeling, fitting

I am looking for a one-dimensional distribution that can be fit to bus-delays. The data are real numbers (positive and negative), and exhibit both skewness and kurtosis.

Which distribution should I use to fit these data?

I would like to compute MAP or ML estimates, and I am using Matlab.

Comment: There's an infinite number of distributions that can be positive and negative and are both skew and have excess kurtosis. Why do you need to fit a distribution at all? You want to compute MAP or ML estimates of what? What's the underlying point of all this?

Comment: @Glen_b: The point is to learn a prior distribution that can be used to compute the posterior on the bus's departure time given when you arrived at the bus stop.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but it raises another confusion for me --  you want to base your prior off the same data you estimate the parameters from?

Comment: I am sorry to have confused you. In the first step, I estimate the distribution of the bus's inter-arrival times. In the second step, I use this distribution to compute how likely you are to have missed the bus if you arrive x minutes past the scheduled departure and how long you should expect to wait.

Answer (score 1):

The classic distribution for the waiting time between events in a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) is the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). Bus time arrivals would be a good example of a Poisson process. However, there are probably different average arrivals/waiting times as most bus schedules have day, evening, night, and weekend/holiday schedules. My suggestion would be to break up and re-aggregate your data into like-schedule buckets (all rush hour together, all weekend together) and then start with fitting an exponential distribution.

Comment: So when you arrive at a bus stop & someone tells you that you just missed a bus; & when you arrive, & someone tells you the last bus was half an hour ago: you'd estimate the same waiting time in each case? The memorylessness assumption seems rather strong for this case, even if you don't live in Switzerland.

Comment: Of course, no model will reflect reality $100\%$. However 1) *perceived* waiting time and psychological frustration does not mean that the actual events will change (unless you're truly psionic, in which case the NSA may want to contact you) and 2) the exponential remains the best distribution with which to start and may be more than adequate for @Falk's purposes.. If the fit isn't good, a Gamma or Weibull could be investigated. Lastly, you may be interested in this post on the [unreliable friends distribution](http://bit.ly/18MsUWL) although the conditional waiting is going the other way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exponential distribution is not a good fit for my data: First, it is only defined for non-negative values, but some delays are negative (i.e. when the bus departured early). Second, according to the exponential distribution the likelihood decays monotonically, but the frequency of delays peaks at an intermediate value (e.g. at about 3.5 minutes). I will try

Comment: I will try shifting the delays such that they are all positive and fitting a Gamma distribution and a Weibull distribution. Thank you!

Comment: @Falk If you have the delays, you should be able to shift and turn them into the actual waiting times, which will all be non-negative. You could model the waiting times and then shift them back to delays by subtracting the "official interarrival time" (I don't want to say "expected" as the expected time from the distribution will not necessarily equal the posted arrival times).

Comment: @Avraham: Thank you for this suggestion. I will shift the data by the scheduled interval between busses and fit waiting time distributions (Erlang, Gamma, Weibull).

Answer (score -2):

I'd try log-normal first. You should inspect a histogram to see what it looks like?!

Comment: -1 Lognormal is inappropriate for data that have any appreciable chance of being non-positive.